# Modal inside translated div does not occupy the whole screen

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I basically have a component that slides up my page from the bottom and occupies `80%` of the height. Inside this component I have a `modal` component. When I open this modal, it does not occupy the whole page as it should. I tracked down the reason for this being the `transform: translateY()` that I use to animate my component sliding. If I remove the transformation, the modal does fill the whole page.

I have made a simplified fiddle ilustrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/70yopxg6/2/

Note that setting the transformation with `transform: translateY(0)` animates the sliding but the modal does not open correctly. If we set the transformation as `transform: none` then it kinda works. But what if I have another transformations applied besides `translateY`? How would I do it without cleaning all transformations? I would like to also understand why this happens.

I'm using Chrome 70 by the way.

Thanks